# Flex Bulder 3 Version Pro or Not Identification

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

How do I tell if an installed Flex Builder 3 is the Pro (or Not) version.

Help | About only states Flex Builder 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help > Product Details > Configuration Details

Mine says:

> *** Adobe Flex Builder 3: Flex Builder 3-Professional Edition - Educational

I have an educational license, since I work at a university; but you can see that it says "Professional."

Answer (score 0):

Help > Manage Flex Licences

Mine Says: Current Licence: Proffesional Edition - Upgrade from standard